# What is the proper way to add a file to XYZ.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt?

Tags: msbuild

My build code creates one extra file in the bin folder. I want it cleaned when the solution is cleaned. However, the name of the file is determined by the AssemblyName property of the project. So, if this property is changed (rare, but happens), then the only way to have the old file cleaned is if it is written in XYZ.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt.

Do I just write to XYZ.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt whenever I create my file or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found it.

Just add the file to the `FileWrites` item list, like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FileWrites Include="$(SomeFileYouWantCleanedUpOnClean)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

In my code this is part of a target than runs BeforeBuild and BeforeRebuild, but it may as well work when defined in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to clean up a file is to write your own build target in the *.csproj file. Like this:

```
<Target Name="MyClean" AfterTargets="Clean">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ToBeCleaned Include="$(SomeFileYouWantCleanedUpOnClean)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Delete Files="@(ToBeCleaned)" />
</Target>
```

You should never ever had to modify (nor care about) the FileListAbsolute.txt file.

Comment: In my example, I made it run after the clean. But you make it run before too. it's up to you.

Comment: There is a reason why msbuild has this file - to handle renames. If the name of my file changes during the implementation, then the old file will be left on disk.

Comment: I have to disagree with your last statement. Appending to `FileWrites` for cleaning up output files that are created by custom MSBuild targets is actually on par with [Microsoft's recommended practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/msbuild-best-practices-for-creating-reliable-builds-part-1).

Comment: Still, your approach is relevant for files that are dynamically created by targets but not in one of the output folders. According to the doc mentioned above, `FileWrites` entries that aren't located in one of the build output folders will be ignored, leaving `Delete` task as the only alternative to clean up after tool packages that won't do it on their own (looking at you, `docfx.console` ! ). That's not the op's scenario, but still a decent advice for anyone out there looking to extend the cleaning operation to files that aren't part of the output folders.